# Magento 1.9.3 Removing Add to Compare / Add to List in Product view

Tags: magento-1.9.3.2

Need help removing the following from beneath the Add to Cart.
Thanks.

[image]

```
        <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
            <div class="add-to-box">
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                    <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || 
                $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')-
                >getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?>
                </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
        <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <div class="add-to-box">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this code in your **`view.phtml`**

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
```

or Remove this Block in your **`local.xml`**

```
<remove name="addto" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Removing in the view.phtml worked but the text **OR** still lingers. Any help there would be most appreciated.  Thanks again.

Comment: Command this line <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>

Comment: Adding that line to the view.phtml file removes all features of the product page including the footer yet the **OR** still remains.

Comment: Update your .phtml file here

Comment: Blocking the code in local.xml didn't seem to do the trick. Using Template Path Hints these Add to options appeared in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/amlist/rewrite/catalog_product_view_addto.pthml. I blocked <ul> to the add-to-links which has achieved desired behavior.  Thank you again.

Comment: if you are using 3rd party module then you need to check override ptml

Comment: Still having issue removing the OR in the image above. As mentioned I have commented out the code for the 'add-to' links within the aforementioned file however the OR still remains. Any additional assistance would be great.

Comment: Post your code ......